# Alternative to disappearing time-series: Time-series database modelling

Tags: database-design, time-series, influxdb, prometheus

I'm new to time-series database design.

One of the guiding principles I've read was to avoid having a high number of time-series (eg. [InfluxDb recommendations](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#don-t-have-too-many-series)) or time-series that are short-lived / die out.

As an exercise I'm trying to model metrics of github repositories. I want to track total number of comments / commits / changed lines aggregated by various attributes. My initial idea was to push metrics on a per pull request, and do all aggregations through queries.

```
{
   labels: {
      pr: 1234, 
      repo: aRepo, 
      author: personA
   }
   values: {
      commits: 5,
      changed_files: 2,
      comments: 0
      status: Open
   }
}
```

However this seems to go against recommendations (pull requests get closed and become constant). Alternative would be to pre-compute aggregations before pushing them to the database. This, however it results in less granular data, and loss of data.

What is the optimal strategy here, for cases of ephemeral time series.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb for figuring out what make series & what are measures is the considering cardinality of the data set (series):

**1)** low cardinality (less variable) values goes to tags - that's your grouping/aggregation props

**2)** high cardinality (highly variable) values are measurement values themselves - that is what you'd be aggregating/do calculations upon in aforementioned groups

By this rule, `pr id` goes into values (they're unique per repo - high cardinality), while `status` is definitely a tag (you dubbed it label).

Do this, and you'll be fine with your timeseries.

Comment: That is great feedback. However some time-series DB use the timestamp as the identifier and will overwrite data points with similar timestamp and label combinations - eg InfluxDb. In this example if we measure 2 pull requests at the same time instant, with the same label set, the previous will be overwritten.

Comment: I would rather wonder if other timeseries DB's won't do that. After all, that's a TIMEseries, hence the the timing is the ultimate key for the point of measurement! Then, there's tags that identify what the point exactly is, if there's multiple. So, if the time the point is taken is the same, the point identifiers are the same - what could be the reason to separate them? I'm not able to find any, can you do that?